# Is selling alcohol-based tinctures haram?

Tags: halal-haram, alcohol, business, medical, health

I am in the process of establishing a business, which will offer products for health, body and beauty. The items that I plan to offer includes but are not limited to herbs, vitamins, organic food, tinctures etc. My concern is the sale of alcohol-based tinctures.

> A tincture is typically an alcoholic extract of plant or animal material or solution of such, or of a low volatility substance (such as iodine and mercurochrome). -- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tincture)

You might know that the most potent form of tincture consists of up to 50% alcohol and there is a wide market for that. There are other alternatives available but majority of the producers and consumers favor alcohol as it increases the shelf life of products. Being a Muslim, I do realize that it may be permissible to consume alcohol in small quantities for its medicinal properties as long as there is absolutely no alternative available.

Tinctures are consumed in small quantities as well (5-8 drops) but my concern is the profit I get on selling them. My market is huge and my customers include Muslims and non-Muslims. I am confused, is it permissible for me to sell such products or is it absolutely NO NO?